# WP7/Silverlight: how to disable/remove adctrol from visual tree

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am building a app that supports trial and I want to show ads in trials and no ads in paid. Upon investigation I found that the only way to disable the ads for paid version is to remove the adcontrol completely from the visual tree.

Now my question is how do I remove the adcontrol from my visual tree in my code when I detect it is a paid version and not a trial. Can you please help?

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,0,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
<Grid Grid.Row="0">          
    ...
    </Grid>    
     <Grid Grid.Row="1">
       ...
    </Grid>    
     <Grid Grid.Row="2">
 <ad:AdControlx:Name="itemAds" .../>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to name the grid:

```
var parent = itemAds.Parent as Grid;
if (parent != null)
{
    parent.Children.Remove(itemAds);
}
```

Comment: (presuming that its always in a grid.  otherwise, could be `itemAds.Parent as Panel` or whatever the container is.

Comment: One thing about this approach though is that you are NOT removing the binding to the ad events.  That means you are still keeping it in memory.  You have to unbind all the event listeners to really get rid of it.

Answer (score 5):

If you set the Visibility of the control to `Visibility.Collapsed` it will be removed from the visual tree.
You therefore just need one line of code:

```
itemAds.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you name the Grid that is wrapping the AdControl and then call, myGrid.Children.Clear() ?